# How to use .hasClass to toggle position correctly?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have tried to use `.toggle` to toggle between animations like so, but it didn't work... e.g.,

```
$('.login').toggle(
    function()
       {
          $('#panel').animate({
          height: "150", 
          padding:"20px 0",
          backgroundColor:'#000000',
          opacity:.8
          }, 500);
       },
       function()
       {
          $('#panel').animate({
          height: "0", 
          padding:"0px 0",
          opacity:.2
          }, 500);
   });
```

so I switched to using if statements with classes, but I can't figure out how to stop the animation from reverting back to its old position again.

```
$("#navigation").click(function() {
    $("#navigation").animate( {
        top: "0px"
    }, 200);
    $("#navigation").addClass("here");
});

$("#navigation").click(function() {
    if($("#navigation").hasClass("here") ) {
        $("#navigation").animate( {
        top: "-180px"
    }, 200);
    }
});
```

Comment: why there are 2 functions for `$("#navigation").click`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** If you use `hasclass` then, it'll be like below one:

```
 $("#navigation").click(function () {
        if ($("#navigation").hasClass("here")) {
            $("#navigation").animate({
                top: "-180px"
            }, 200);
        }
        else {
            $("#navigation").animate({
                top: "0px"
            }, 200);
            $("#navigation").addClass("here");
        }
    });
```

**2.** And with `toggleclass`:

```
$("#navigation").click(function() {
$(this).toggleClass('here');
$("#navigation").animate( {
  top: $(this).css('top') == "0px" ? "-180px" : "0px";
}, 200);
});
```

*Note:* Stay away from toggleClass because it adds an error source of what knowing the state before using it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it works! And thanks to everyone else that answered my question.
I'm quite a noob as webdesign, just started self teaching. I have other questions if someone would like to answer them.

Answer (score 0):

See `.toggle(fn, fn)` is now removed from the latest jQuery library, so it won't work. There are other ways to do it. you can use `.toggleClass()` and place the `css`'s top property to 0 to -180:

```
$("#navigation").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('here'); // toggle it here
    $("#navigation").stop(true, true).animate( {
      top: $(this).css('top') == "0px" ? "-180px" : "0px"; // toggle the top here
    }, 200);
});
```

another suggestion is use `.stop(true, true)` to stop the multiple click's wierd behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a single click handler then set the `top` value based on the presents of the class.

In your case every click will trigger both the handlers so first the top is set as `0` then as `-180`

```
$("#navigation").click(function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        top: $(this).hasClass("here") ? '-180px' : "0px"
    }, 200).toggleClass("here");
});
```